# Can you get tweets by hashtag or username with V1.1

Tags: twitter

I need a little help with my search query for Twitter's API V1.1. I'm wanting to get all tweets that either have the username @dewsly or include the hashtag #dewsly. Right now it seems to be doing an "AND" so it's only bringing back tweets that have the hashtag #dewsly and are from the user @dewsly.

What should my query be to change it to an "OR"?

```
?q=#dewsly+from:dewsly
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming You are using ruby then you simply wite this code and get tweets

```
    consumer = OAuth::Consumer.new(consumer_key,consumer_secet,{ :site => "http://api.twitter.com",
      :scheme => :header
    })
  token_hash = { :oauth_token =>your_access_token,:oauth_token_secret =>your_secret}
  user_access_token = OAuth::AccessToken.from_hash(consumer, token_hash)
```

If you new with twitter keys then simply go `https://dev.twitter.com` and create new app and get all keys

```
request_url = "http://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=#{user_screen_name}"
                request_url =URI.encode(request_url)
                response = access_token.request(:get, request_url)
                body = response.body
                search = JSON.parse(body)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm actually writing this in PHP and am using this library https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php/wiki/Twitter-API-PHP-Wiki. Any thoughts on how to get it working within this framework?